# showing $\int_a^x |f(t)-g(t))|dt \leq (x-a) \max_{a\leq t\leq b} |f(t)-g(t)|$

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

How to show this? $x\in[a,b]$, $f,g$ are continuous.
$$1)\quad\int_a^x |f(t)-g(t))|dt \leq (x-a) \max_{a\leq t\leq b} |f(t)-g(t)|$$

Someone suggested:

$$2)\quad\int_a^x |f(t) - g(t)| dt \leq \int_a^x \max_{a \leq t \leq b} |f(u) - g(u)| dt \leq \max_{a \leq u \leq b} |f(u) - g(u)| \cdot \int_a^x dt = \max \{\text{junk}\} \cdot (x - a)$$

but that still confuses me, since here they have changed the variable from $t$ to $u$, and I don't know if it even works. How to prove $1)$? Is $2)$ correct?

Answer (score 1):

Let's define $$M = \max_{a \leq t \leq b} |f(t) - g(t)|$$

Then, you have for any $t \in [a,x]$

$$ |f(t)-g(t)| \leq M$$

And as the integral is increasing, it gives you

$$\int_a^x |f(t)-g(t)| dt \leq \int_a^x M dt$$

And the right side is equal to $(x-a)M$

So you got
$$\int_a^x |f(t)-g(t)| dt \leq  (x-a)\max_{a \leq t \leq b} |f(t) - g(t)|$$